# Is there a way to stop QWindowsNativeFileDialog::OnSelectionChange(Qurl...) from logging out into the command line?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I see that the file dialog widget in PyQt5 logs out a `QWindowsNativeFileDialogBase::onSelectionChange (QUrl...)` message into the command line every time I interact with it. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

---

#### Current Output:

You can see that when I click on "codetesting.py," the message pops up in the command line.

[image]

---

#### Logout example:

```
QWindowsNativeFileDialogBase::onSelectionChange (QUrl("file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/WaferMapViewerProject/src/main/python/codetesting.py")) 1
```

---

#### Runnable code:

When you run this code, a window pops up with a button in the middle. The file dialog will open when you click it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 50
        self.top = 50
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100, 70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I see messages in command line when I run many programs and I don't waste time to try to remove it. Normally GUI programs are executed without command line and nobody see these messages.

Comment: @furas Wouldn't this affect the efficiency of the program if the user tries to input many files at once?

Comment: it is only one small message. It takes only few milliseconds. It can't slow down program. You need much more time to move mouse and click button or filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable logging using [`QLoggingCategory`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLoggingCategory

QLoggingCategory.setFilterRules('qt.qpa.dialogs.debug=false')
```

Or

```
import os
# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    os.environ["QT_LOGGING_RULES"] = "*.debug=false"

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # ...
```

Comment: I get a `from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QRect, QSize, Qt, QRectF, QLoggingCategory....ImportError: cannot import name 'QLoggingCategory'` error instead. I am not sure why that happens.

Comment: @burntchowmein  The QLoggingCategory class represents a category, or 'area' in the logging infrastructure. This class was introduced in Qt 5.2.

Comment: @burntchowmein Which version of pyqt5 do you use? How did you install pyqt5?

Comment: I believe it's 5.13

Comment: @burntchowmein How did you install PyQt5?, try update: `python -m pip install pyqt5 --upgrade`